# How do I make a stream that inserts a new line after each output operation?

Tags: c++, stream, iostream

I want to make `std::cout` insert a newline after each output operation. For example, doing this:

```
std::cout << 1 << 2 << 3;
```

or

```
std::cout << 1;
std::cout << 2;
std::cout << 3;
```

Should output with:

> 1
>   2
>   3

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to create your own simple streaming wrapper. You would need a templated `operator<<` that forwards the parameter to std::cout (or to some other wrapped stream), and adds a `std::endl` afterwards.

I won't post the entire class, but the operator could look something like this:

```
template <typename T>
my_stream_class &my_stream_class::operator<<(T const &value) {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: @acron Almost, your stream operator should `return *this;`, otherwise you won't be able to do `log << "Hello" << "World";`

Comment: Is there any way to alter it so that `cout << 0; cout << 1 << 2 << 3;` produces `0\n123`?

Comment: @acron Yes, by returning a temporary object that will append `std::endl` upon destruction: http://ideone.com/5ocnsj

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tried. I don't know if it is the best approach though:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename CharT, typename Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>>
struct my_stream : std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>
{
    my_stream(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& str) : os(str) {}

    template <typename T>
    friend std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& operator <<(my_stream& base, T const& t)
    {
        return base.os << t << std::endl;
    }

    std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os;
};

int main()
{
    my_stream<char> stream(std::cout);

    stream << 1;
    stream << 2;
    stream << 3;
}
```

Output:

> 1
>   2
>   3

Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work for a one-liner `stream << 1 << 2 << 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly great but you could try using this. Basically, I am trying to overload the operator '<<'.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class my_N
{
    private:
       int number;
    public:
       //required constructor
       my_N(){
           number = 0;
       }
       my_N(int N1){
           number = N1;
       }
       friend ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, const my_N &N )
       {
           output << N.number << "\n";
           return output;
       }
};

int main()
{
    my_N N1(1), N2(2), N3(3);
    cout << N1;
    cout << N2;
    cout << N3;
    return 1;
}
```

Result:

> 1
>     2
>     3

It even works for `cout << N1 << N2 << N3;`